# How to print to bluetooth printer from vue/capacitor app?

Tags: vue.js, cordova, vuejs2, cordova-plugins, capacitor

Like the title says, I'm trying to physically print to a bluetooth (receipt) printer from my vue / capacitor app. The application is installed on an Android device using an APK.

Currently my solution is to have a server on location that the vue app connects to. The vue app sends the request to my server which in turn connects to the bluetooth printer and prints the receipt. I know this is a very cumbersome way to achieve my goal, that's why I'm trying to improve it.

I've tried several of the available cordova plugins but none seem to work. I keep getting errors before even being connected to the printer. I've spent many hours trying (i think) all popular plugins but I can't seem to figure it out. Maybe I'm just using them wrong but I really can't get it to work.

For example I've tried [this](https://danielsogl.gitbook.io/awesome-cordova-plugins/bluetooth-serial) plugin. But I get the following error: `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'cordova-plugin-bluetooth-serial' in '******'`.

Does anyone know any solution? Any experience with a plugin that you know works? Maybe another way to do this? Would love any suggestions at all as I'm completely stuck on this problem.